# Simulators are not showing up for every newly created project

Tags: xcode

When I try to create new project in Xcode 8,simulators are not showing up which are already downloaded in previous project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously simulators downloaded are of version 9.3 and deployment target is set to 10.0.Now I set deployment target to 9.3 and simulators are visible now.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the name of your project (which is on the right hand side of the Run button). Three options will appear.

1. Edit scheme
2. New scheme
3. Manage scheme
   You can click on "New scheme" and then click on "OK" in popup window.

You will get the simulators back. Cheers.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I found the issue,Deployment target was not set correctly,I correct it and simulators shows up instantly.

Comment: Did the simulators come back or they still haven't?